# Why does this work on paper but the logic does not work on code

Tags: java, arrays

I have some code that finds if there are any 4 consecutive numbers that are the same(vertically or horizontally) and then print out true or false accordingly. Whilst i believe i have done it correctly, it doesn't work. Weird part is that on paper it does work! The code is written in java. The code :

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rows = input.nextInt();
        int columns = input.nextInt();
        int [][] integers = new int[rows][columns];
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
                integers[i][j] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
        if(Sinexomena4(integers)){
            System.out.println("true");
        }else{
            System.out.println("false");
        }
        
    }
    
    public static Boolean Sinexomena4(int [][] values){
        //Horizontal
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j <= values[0].length - 4; j++){
                if (values[j][i] == values[j + 1][i] &&
                    values[j + 1][i] == values[j + 2][i] && 
                    values[j + 2][i] == values[j + 3][i] ){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        //Vertical
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j <= values[0].length - 4; j++){
                if (values[i][j] == values[i][j + 1] &&
                    values[i][j + 1] == values[i][j + 2] &&
                    values[i][j + 2] == values[i][j + 3] ){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        //Diagonal
        //Down
        for (int j = 0; j <= values.length - 4; j++){
            for(int i = 0; i <= values[0].length - 4;i++){
                if (values[i][j] == values[i + 1][j + 1] &&
                    values[i + 1][j + 1] == values[i + 2][j + 2] && 
                    values[i + 2][j + 2] == values[i + 3][j + 3]){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            
        }
        //Up
        for (int j = values.length; j > 2; j--){
            for(int i = 0; i <= values[0].length - 4;i++){
                if (values[j][i] == values[j - 1][i + 1] && 
                    values[j - 1][i + 1] == values[j - 2][i + 2] && 
                    values[j - 2][i + 2] == values[j - 3][i + 3]){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}


this is the input
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0
```

**Edit** : Everything works perfect besides the second diagonal. The second diagonal works just fine for a 4x4 matrix but any bigger than that throws an error

Does anyone have any idea why this is not working? I have debugged it a bit but i did not have any luck!(also i am new to stack overflow go easy on me :))

Comment: Please let me know if you need any more info!

Comment: Can you give more information about how it doesn't work? Like an example input with expected output and actual output.

Comment: Two questions/issues... (1) You make 4 comparisons, but to check equality of 4 values, it should only be necessary to make 3 comparisons. (2) In the horizontal part, you are using j to loop over the first array dimension, but in the vertical loop, you are using i. This only works for a quadratic array. - Is that really how it should be?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon How do i upload pictures? i want to show you what you want

Comment: Don't upload pictures. Copy and paste text instead.

Comment: 1 2 3 4                                                                                                                       
1 5 8 9                                                                                                                       
1 6 3 8                                                                                                                       
1 9 6 3 
this outputs false when it should output true

Comment: @izydrmr why would i need to only make 3 comparisons? could you give me an example? What do you mean quadratic array? i just want to loop through the entire array!

Comment: At least please add the input you are using. And ideally a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in the current version still has some problems. First, for the horizontal/vertical part, you are still doing 4 comparisons. You might have corrected this in your local version, but the edited code in the original question still has this problem.

A more fundamental problem is that you are mixing up rows and columns. You should use the variables `i` and `j` consistently. Sometimes, you are using `i` for the row, sometimes for the column. Look at the way you are reading the input. The first dimension of your matrix refers to the rows, the second to the columns. Considering the comment in the source code, "horizontal" and "vertical" is the other way around.

If you use more complex use cases, you will see that you are missing cases. For example, the following matrix would not be correctly handled by your code:

```
5 5
2 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 2 1 0
0 0 2 0 0
2 1 1 1 1
```

Your loop bounds also need correction. For quick checking, do the calculation (in your head) for the border cases. In your "diagonal up" case, the loop ends when `j` equals `4`. You are checking the element at index `[j-3][i+3]`, i.e. `[1][i+3]`, but the code never encounters `[0][i+3]`, so you are missing the first column.

Here is a corrected and more consistent version of your code. I included some `println()` statements so it is actually visible where the sequence of numbers is found.

```
public static Boolean Sinexomena4(int [][] values){
    // Horizontal
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= values[0].length - 4; j++){
            if (values[i][j] == values[i][j+1] &&
                    values[i][j+1] == values[i][j+2] &&
                    values[i][j+2] == values[i][j+3]){
                System.out.println("horizontal "+i+" "+j);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    // Vertical
    for (int i = 0; i <= values.length-4; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++){
            if (values[i][j] == values[i+1][j] &&
                    values[i+1][j] == values[i+2][j] &&
                    values[i+2][j] == values[i+3][j]){
                System.out.println("vertical "+i+" "+j);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    //Diagonal
    //Down
    for (int i = 0; i <= values.length - 4; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <= values[0].length - 4; j++){
            if (values[i][j] == values[i + 1][j + 1] &&
                    values[i + 1][j + 1] == values[i + 2][j + 2] &&
                    values[i + 2][j + 2] == values[i + 3][j + 3]){
                System.out.println("diag down "+i+" "+j);
                return true;
            }
        }

    }
    //Up
    for (int i = values.length-1; i >= 3; i--){
        for(int j = 0; j <= values[0].length - 4; j++){
            if (values[i][j] == values[i - 1][j + 1] &&
                    values[i - 1][j + 1] == values[i - 2][j + 2] &&
                    values[i - 2][j + 2] == values[i - 3][j + 3]){
                System.out.println("diag up "+i+" "+j);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

And here are a few more (positive) test cases. When you do testing, make sure to also include some negative test cases! And don't include quadratic matrices only, use some non-quadratic as well!

```
7 4
0 1 0 1
1 0 2 0
0 1 2 1
1 0 2 0
0 1 0 1
1 2 1 0
0 1 0 1

5 5
2 0 1 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 2 1 0
0 0 2 0 0
2 1 1 1 1

5 5
2 0 1 1 0
2 1 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 0
0 0 2 1 0
2 2 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of this condition: **j < values[0].length - 4**, in inner for loop,
you are missing the check of last 4 values in both loops.(horizontal and vertical)

For example, if the row has 6 elements such as 1,2,4,4,4,4.
The inner loop check will only check cases: j=0:{1,2,4,4} and j=1:{2,4,4,4} then value of j will increment to 2  since j<values[0].length - 4 i.e; 2<2 false, the loops exits without checking  the last combination {4,4,4,4}.

I suggest you try with **j <= values[0].length - 4**.

**Edit 1**: Based on @lzydrmr comment,
Written the code as follows:

```
public static Boolean Sinexomena4(int [][] values){
        //Horizontal
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j <= values[0].length - 4; j++){
                if (values[j][i] == values[j + 1][i] &&
                    values[j + 1][i] == values[j + 2][i] && 
                    values[j + 2][i] == values[j + 3][i]){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        //Vertical
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j <= values[0].length - 4; j++){
                if (values[i][j] == values[i][j + 1] &&
                    values[i][j + 1] == values[i][j + 2] &&
                    values[i][j + 2] == values[i][j + 3]){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
return false;
}
```

Comment: I get this error when i have a 4x4 2d array=>

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4                                                        
        at Main.Sinexomena4(Main.java:23)                                                                                     
        at Main.main(Main.java:16)

Comment: You are making 4 comparisons in your code, meaning there are 5 elements involved. But as you only have a 4x4 array, this leads to an out-of-bounds exception.

Comment: can you elaborate on that? i dont really see how there are 5 elements!

Comment: In your code, the following values appear: `values[j][i], values[j + 1][i], values[j + 2][i], values[j + 3][i], values[j + 4]`.  That means, you are referring to the indices j, j+1, j+2, j+3, j+4. For j=0, this means indices 0,1,2,3,4 (5 items). In a 4x4 array, only indices 0,1,2,3 are valid.

Comment: So it actually worked out thanks for the help. I have one more though.

//Up
        for (int j = values.length; j > 3; j--){
            for(int i = 0; i < values[0].length - 4;i++){
                if (values[j][i] == values[j - 1][i + 1] && 
                    values[j - 1][i + 1] == values[j - 2][i + 2] && 
                    values[j - 2][i + 2] == values[j - 3][i + 3]){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

this is supposed to print true for this 
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 
but it prints false. Any ideas?

Comment: for (int j = values.length; j > 3; j--) it will give you exception for when j=values.length and you are trying to access values[j][i] because the maximum value of j could be values.length-1, as indexing starts from 0 in Java. Please find the re-written code.

Comment: the re-written code? The lowest value j acquires is 1, am i wrong?

Comment: Edited my answer and included the code. The lowest value of j is 0. j will have values from 0 to values.length-1.

Comment: i added your code but it doesn't seem to work
this is what i have
```//Up
        for (int j = values.length; j > 3; j--){
            for(int i = 0; i <= values[0].length - 4;i++){
                if (values[j][i] == values[j - 1][i + 1] && 
                    values[j - 1][i + 1] == values[j - 2][i + 2] && 
                    values[j - 2][i + 2] == values[j - 3][i + 3]){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }```

Comment: i must not be getting something here. I now understand why values of j are 0 to values.length - 1

Comment: Edit: the part of the code you just wrote is already done. I now need to find both diagonals. I have something but it is obviously not working

Comment: Can you be elaborate more? Do you want to check all elements in the diagonal of a matrix are of the same value? or to check only 4 elements diagonally same are not.

Comment: I have updated the original post with the diagonal code(for both diagonals)

Comment: i only need to find if there are any 4 consecutive numbers in the diagonals! but my method seems to have a few flaws